# Laravel DateTime error on fresh installation

Tags: laravel

I have install new version of Laravel. After opening it is OK. But If after some time I try to refresh or try to visit another page, it is showing an error. If I restart the server, then for few minutes it is again OK. Older version was OK, this problem I am facing for the first time. Please help.

***ERROR:***

(1/1) Exception
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2018-03-10 11:07:55.-811414) at position 24 (4): Unexpected character

[image]

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: Yes, finally I have got the solution. It is PHP version problem. I have upgraded the PHP latest version 7.2.2 and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Simply generate app key, write in console:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

The "right" way defining default datetimes

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2014-06-23');
```

You can also use a hack using pages.dateformat.default: 'm-d-Y'`

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '06-23-2014');
```

Comment: After generating the key, I haven't got the error. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: Sorry, that error has come back again. I have decided to use older version of laravel

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with fresh install of Laravel 5.4 and PHP 5.6.

I solved it with

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```